# How to Return DTO Nicely Without Closing Connection in WCF

Tags: wcf, channel, faultexception

My WCF Service in C# looks like this.

```
[ServiceContract]
public class MySecretService
{
      [OperationContract]
      [FaultContract(typeof(ErrorMessage))]
      public MyDTO ReturnMyDTOMethod(int id, out string errorMessage)
      {
        try
        {
           //Do stuff...

           //Do some more stuff... pseudocode
          if (biz rule 1 && etc)
          {
            return MyDTO;
          }
          else if (biz rule 2 && etc)
          {
            return null;
          }
          else
          {
            throw new FaultException<ErrorMessage>(blah etc..)
          }
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            throw new FaultException<ErrorMessage>(blah etc...);
        }
     }//end-method
}//end-class
```

The DTO to be returned from the method looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyDTO
{
  [DataMember]
  public XElement XmlRep
  {
    get
    {
        //do something within setter, etc...

    //error occurs prior to returnin from setter, where to i catch it?
    return _xmlRep
    }
    set
    {
    _xmlRep = value;

    }

  }
}
```

The typical examples that i found shows throwing a FaultException from within the method; But in my case, my method does not error; The error occurs at the time when the object is being returned to the client/consumer; i.e when the DataMember/Property XmlRep is being serialized;

So i cannot place the throw FaultException within my method; But i still want to avoid getting
"The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly." and throw the proper error that occurs within the getter.

I have not tried putting try/catch inside the getter of MyDTO, NOR DO I WANT TO BECAUSE i want my DTO to be as simple as possible, and know nothing about FaultExceptions and WCF stuff. Any other ideas ?

EDIT: Just to make it clearer, i know the error is occurring in the Getter of MyDto DataContract; But where else would i throw the FaultException, given that inside the Getter seems to me like a dodgy place to throw it?

EDIT#2: I implemented a catch-all error handler on the service side as suggested by Tim below (using IErrorHandler); this does not work in my specific case. I think this is because the Error does not occur within the OperationContract ReturnMyDTOMethod(), but instead within the MyDto when is being serialized; In other words, it appears the horse has bolted (method returns successfully), and it is to late for the IErrorHandler to be of any use - Specifically ProvideFault() does not fire but HandleError() does fire. Consequently i still get a channel broken message, which requires me to go back to the drawing board - i.e. ensure MyDto does not do anything fancy such as generate an error!

Comment: Instead of casually mentioning you get an error as if it were non-consequential, please post your exception in full!

Comment: @hugh, please re-read the question; i thought it was clear enough, the error is "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly." This error appears on the consumer/client side.

Comment: @joedotnot - you could catch the exception via an implementation of IErrorHandler (option 2 in my answer below) and throw the the FaultException from there, or your service could catch the error when you instantiate the DTO and throw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options I see:

1. It sounds like something in your DataContract isn't able to be serialized.  I would take a look there and determine what that is, why it isn't being serialized, and if there is some other way you can handle the issue within the setter.  You may be able to do that without a try-catch block, depending on what it is.  Without seeing the code or knowing what the actual error is, it's hard to give anything more specific.
2. Implement [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) Interface in your service.  This will catch any unhandled exceptions and you to handle them as your service needs (for example, serializing an error message via FaultException).  There are plenty of examples on the web of how to do that - simply google IErrorHandler and WCF.

My personal preference would be to try approach #1 - there's probably a specific reason (or group of reasons) your DTO isn't serializing, and I feel it's better to handle those issues within the code rather than relying on some sort of global error handler (which is what #2 would be).

Also, depending on the logic in your setter, you may have already made your DTO complex.  I generally try to avoid any logic in my setter unless it's something simple like a null check.

**Added After 2nd Edit in Question**

The documentation for IErrorHandler states:

"Exceptions can occur after all ProvideFault implementations are called and a response message is handed to the channel. If a channel exception occurs (**for example, difficulty serializing the message**) IErrorHandler objects are not notified. In this case, you should make sure that your development environment catches and displays such exceptions to you or makes use of tracing to discover the problem."  (Emphasis mine)

Do you know what is causing the serialization to fail?  If you do, I would think you could address it in the code itself.  Have you enabled tracing? It seems to me that you need to determine why your DTO can't serialize.

Comment: Thanks Tim, you are right about DataContract (i.e. MyDto object) not being able to be serialized; In fact i know exactly what the error is, and it is occuring inside the XmlRep getter property, that was a statement of the known problem. The real question is how would i catch it NICELY on the consumer or client side, that is, instead of receiving the generic Wcf Channel broken message "The underlying conn was closed.. blah etc".. i want to throw a nice message that the client can receive. Any further input appreciated.

Comment: If you can't fix your DTO so it doesn't break when being serialized, then go with option 2 (implement global error handling with IErrorHandler) or have your service populate/fill the DTO in a try-catch block.  You can then return a user-friendly FaultException message.

Comment: Tim, you seem to be saying if i go with option 2 (the global error handler), i cannot use option 1 ? (i.e. there would be no point in throwing localized FaultException at the method/OperationContract level, because they will go thru the global error handler anyway? Please confirm.

Comment: @joedotnot - You could use either or both options.  The goal of option 1 is to avoid throwing exceptions all together by making the code robust.  The intent behind option 2, at least as I've used it, to catch any exception the service throws that are *not* handled in the service code.  Unhandled exceptions in the service will fault the channel; implementing a global error handler gives you a way to both prevent the channel faulting and to present a nice message to the client.

Comment: Tim, Option 2 of using the IErrorHandler does not work in my specific example. See my second edit above at the end of the question.

Comment: responding to your question "Do you know what is causing the serialization to fail?". Yes i do, some logic which i put on the Getter (on purpose); It was never an issue of me not knowing where the error was coming from - rather it was about catching such an error, AND still return a nice message, but as per your edit the doco confirms IErrorHandler does not cater for this scenario. Thanks for all your input.